# Cannot debug blazor client side

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to debug client side Blazor app in Edge Chromium or even Chrome. I ran Edge with this command :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

But when I hit the keys `Shift + Alt + D`

When it tries to connect :

> http://localhost:64589/_framework/debug?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64589%2F

I am getting this error : This localhost page can’t be found

Project is compiled in debug mode, it is actually the Blazing Pizza from the Blazor workshop provider by Microsoft.

When I just run the Blazor client project without the Server side I can actually connect to debugger but nothing happens ont the Client as the server is not running.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Mine works only Microsoft Edge Dev, and only if I use the entire link `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:64589/`. The blazor app shows as **This tab is inactive** but you can put the other tab up next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in [this Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/issues/76):

Looks like BlazingPizza.Server lacks a call to app.UseBlazorDebugging(); inside the if (env.IsDevelopment()) block in Startup.cs.